# Java Swing GUI: How to put components from bottom to top but not vice versa?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Would like to put components from bottom to top, in context of my `JFrame` window size being fixed at a value (by `JFrame.setSize()`). I've attempted various approaches, such as the most popular one `BorderLayout` where theoretically I just have to add the `JPanel`'s by stating `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, but they just can't get it done if there're not any components on top of the `BorderLayout`.

What I'm encountering now is:

[image: current problem]

And what I'm expecting to attain is:

[image: expectation]

In other words, what I want to accomplish is to stick the `JPanel`'s onto the bottom edge with nothing else on top of them. But if there're no components stated e.g. `BorderLayout.CENTER` or `BorderLayout.NORTH`, then the above problem occurred.

Any idea, please :D?

(Btw, it seems in Java Swing, adding components from bottom to top is just more difficult than that from right to left?)

Comment: BorderLayout.PAGE_END (ie SOUTH) should work (it works for me). If you have a problem then post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a frame with a JButton added to the PAGE_END. As you resize the frame the button will stick to the bottom. Then do the same thing with a JPanel containing the button to verify the concept works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ^^ I'm sorry for being that new to the forum... I'll definitely try more on my own first and give you guys my minimal example later.

Comment: *I'll definitely try more on my own first and give you guys my minimal example later.* - and what happened? Either delete the question or post your followup [mre].